# How to pause Text Javascript / var textarray?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to Pause and Resume the javascript by clicking on the page.

I have text scrolling that changes by fading in and out.

The solutions I found online were how to pause marquee's, but I think that solution doesn't apply since my code doesn't use marquee tags.

Also for my text scrolling I'm not showing text, but images.

I was wondering how could I go about pausing and resuming the images by clicking on the page?

```
<div id="menu">
      <button id="start-stop">Start/stop</button>
</div>

<div id="random_text"></div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
  });

  var textarray = [
    "<img class=\"tall\" src=\"1.png\" alt=\"1\"></img><span class=\"by\">Example</span>" ,
    "<img class=\"wide\" src=\"2.png\" alt=\"2\"></img><span class=\"by\">Example</span>",
    "<img class=\"wide\" src=\"3.png\" alt=\"3\"></img><span class=\"by\">Example</span>",
    "<img class=\"wide\" src=\"4.png\" alt=\"4\"></img><span class=\"by\">Example</span>",

  ];
  var firstTime = true;

  function RndText() {
    var rannum = Math.floor(Math.random() * textarray.length);
    if (firstTime) {
      $('#random_text').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeOut('fast');
      });
      firstTime = false;
    }
    $('#random_text').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).html(textarray[rannum]).fadeIn('fast');
    });
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var containerHeight = $(".container").height();
    // $(".container").css("top", (windowHeight / 2 - containerHeight * 0.7) + "px");
  }

  $(function() {
    // Call the random function when the DOM is ready:
    RndText();
  });
    var inter = setInterval(function() {
    intervalRunning = true;
    RndText();
  }, 3000);
});

$(document).on('click', '#start-stop', function(){
  if (intervalRunning) {
    intervalRunning = false;
    clearInterval(inter);
  } else {
    inter = setInterval(function() {
      intervalRunning = true;
      RndText();
    }, 3000);
  }
})

function toggle_visibility(id) {
                   var e = document.getElementById(id);
                   if(e.style.display == 'block')
                      e.style.display = 'none';
                   else
                      e.style.display = 'block';
                }

    </script>
```

Comment: ok, so, you have an interval that controls when the images rotate. so, uhm... maybe try stopping the interval?

Answer (score 0):

[I've created a jsbin to show a basic solution.](http://jsbin.com/buqade/edit?html,js,output)

Since you are using jQuery, I would change how everything is structured.  I would wrap the code in `$(document).ready`, so that it fires once the DOM is ready.

Create a `bool` at the outset to track if the interval is running:

```
var running = false;
```

Create a handler for the interval to turn on or off as needed:

```
var handleInterval = function(){
    if (running) {
      running = false;
      clearInterval(intObj);    
    } else {
      intObj = setInterval(function(){
        running = true;
        RndText();
      }, 1500);
    }
  };
```

Set a handler for the button:

```
$(document).on("click", "#pause_me", function(){
    handleInterval();
  });
```

Kick the whole thing off with a call to handleInterval:

```
handleInterval();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. After Kevin B's answer I started searching for "start & pause setInterval" I tried your solution but when I did the images stopped rotating completely instead of being able to start and pause. Is there another solution or perhaps a link you would recommend for me to look at?

Comment: I forgot to set intervalRunning to false.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Okay so I added your change and now the images are rotating again. Except when I click on the start/stop button it doesn't stop. I've added your java code, and a start/stop button, am I missing something?

Comment: did you modify the code for the on click function to reference your new button?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, so I don't think so. Would it be easier if I created a jsfiddle?

Comment: Okay I see where you made a change saying to add the id of a new button. I added the id of my button but still no luck stoping and starting the loop. I updated the code to show what I have

Comment: I updated my answer.  Hopefully this clears things up.